# None of the jQuery scripts on my Wordpress site are working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a site using a modified theme and a number of plugins. My knowledge of js is not good at all, so please accept my apologies if this has come up before.
http://www.georgvoros.com/

None of the js seems to be running including the slider, navigation dropdowns, and lightbox scripts. I have updated Wordpress to 3.61 and jQuery to 1.10.2.

I get the following errors in the Chrome inspect elements window.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.tools.min.js?ver=1.2.7:13

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchstart' of undefined jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (b,c,d){var e=b.split(".")[0],f;b=b.split(".")[1];f=e+"-"+b;if(!d){d=c;c=a.Widget}a.expr[":"][f]=function(c){return!!a.data(c,b)};a[e]=a[e]||{};a[e][b]=function(a,b){if(arguments.length){this._createWidget(a,b)}};var g=new c;g.options=a.extend(true,{},g.options);a[e][b].prototype=a.extend(true,g,{namespace:e,widgetName:b,widgetEventPrefix:a[e][b].prototype.widgetEventPrefix||b,widgetBaseClass:f},d);a.widget.bridge(b,a[e][b])} has no method 'extend' jquery-ui.js?ver=3.6.1:539
```

I have read about "$" variables causing problems but I do not understand where I need to change things.

In head.php is the following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // initialise plugins
        jQuery(function(){
            // main navigation init
             jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
                delay:       <?php echo of_get_option('sf_delay'); ?>,      // one second delay on mouseout 
                animation:   {opacity:'<?php echo of_get_option('sf_f_animation'); ?>'<?php if (of_get_option('sf_sl_animation')=='show') { ?>,height:'<?php echo of_get_option('sf_sl_animation'); ?>'<?php } ?>}, // fade-in and slide-down animation
                speed:       '<?php echo of_get_option('sf_speed'); ?>',  // faster animation speed 
                autoArrows:  <?php echo of_get_option('sf_arrows'); ?>,   // generation of arrow mark-up (for submenu)
                dropShadows: false
            }); 

            // prettyphoto init
            jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                animation_speed:'normal',
                slideshow:5000,
                autoplay_slideshow: false,
                overlay_gallery: true
            });

            // Initialize the gallery
            jQuery("#gallery .touch-item").touchTouch();


        });

</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Init for audiojs
        audiojs.events.ready(function() {
            var as = audiojs.createAll();
        });

        // Init for si.files
        SI.Files.stylizeAll();
        $(function(){
            $('.sf-menu > li').append('<span class="bg-menu"></span>');
            $('.sf-menu > li:last').addClass('last');
            $('.recent-posts.services li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('nomargin');
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 10) {
                jQuery('input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]').hover(function(){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('submit-hover')
                 },
                     function(){
                      jQuery(this).removeClass('submit-hover')
                 });    
            }
        });

        jQuery(function() {

            $('.right-content-area #widget_search.box h3').each(function(index) {
                //get the first word
                var firstWord = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];

                //wrap it with span
                var replaceWord = "<span>" + firstWord + "</span>";

                //create new string with span included
                var newString = $(this).html().replace(firstWord, replaceWord);

                //apply to the divs
                $(this).html(newString);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

In theme-scripts.php is:

```
    <?php
/*  Register and load javascript
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function my_script() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', false, '1.10.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), '2.6.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/superfish.js', array('jquery'), '1.7.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), '1.3');
        wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array('jquery'), '3.1.5');
        wp_enqueue_script('tools', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.tools.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.7');
        wp_enqueue_script('mobilemenu', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js', array('jquery'), '1.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('loader', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.loader.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('swfobject', get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js', array('jquery'), '2.3');
        wp_enqueue_script('twitter', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.twitter.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('flickr', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.flickrush.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('touch', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/touchTouch.jquery.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('si_files', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/si.files.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('audiojs', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/audiojs/audio.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('camera', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/camera.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.3');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_script');


/*  Register and load admin javascript
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tz_admin_js($hook) {
    if ($hook == 'post.php' || $hook == 'post-new.php') {
        wp_register_script('tz-admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.custom.admin.js', 'jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('tz-admin');
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','tz_admin_js',10,1);
?>
```

I cannot see that the site is loading more than one version of jQuery either.

Comment: if `jQuery.browser` is undefined, chances are the script(s) you're using relied on an earlier version of jQuery (but `$.browser`'s been gone since 1.9). try including jQuery Migrate (found @jquery.com)

Comment: To me it seems that it is your `jquery-ui.js` ->`http://www.georgvoros.com/wp-content/plugins/form-maker/js/jquery-ui.js?ver=3.6.1` that is currupted or too old. And all your errors correspond to UI plugins ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your site relies on a lot of old jQuery (for example jQuery Tools isn't very commonly used these days and hasn't been for several years due to the popularity of the more maintained jQuery UI).  Updating to the latest version of jQuery probably just broke most of your outdated scripts.

You might be able to fix it by simply including the [jQuery Migrate](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js) official plugin, which adds backwards compatibility for old jQuery features from previous versions that have since been deprecated or removed.

Just include it with `wp_enqueue_script()` immediately after your jQuery `wp_enqueue_script()` call and with any luck that will fix many if not all of your problems.

If that doesn't fix it, you will need to address the problems one by one and either reimplement them with more modern techniques or update their individual script dependencies.

Comment: +1 for the migrate plugin. I had a similar issue with the old version of fancybox and a newer jquery version, and infact it was because $.browser wasn't defined anymore. The migrate plugin fixed that for me.

Comment: So it turns out that I made a noob error by thinking a server update broke my scripts and updated wordpress and all the plugins when I had in fact just installed the Form Maker Plugin. 

I have updated the theme-scripts.php file with the following:

`code`   
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', false, '1.10.2');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
wp_enqueue_script('migrate', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.1'); `code`

Still not fixed. I will remove Form Maker and try again. tks

Comment: Thank you for your help @ennui that worked. 
I have a glitch with the mobile menu appearing when it shouldn't, but I am confident I'll find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are caused by some functions missing in your version of jQuery...

`jQuery.browser` (or `$.browser`) was removed in version 1.9 of jQuery. It seems that some code in your site was written for an older version of jQuery.

You could downgrade to an earlier version, or update the Javascript on your site to work with jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: @davidkonrad What runs 1.10.2? There's lots of plugins on the OPs site which rely on an older version of jQuery, yet the version which is loaded is 1.10.2.

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes. Well done. And that is the problem.

Comment: Yeas, but refering to $.browser doesnt tilt a whole range of plugins

Comment: @davidkonrad Deleting your first comments make mine nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry - it was a useless comment, therefore I deleted it